# Chern class and Euler class

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

We know that for a complex vector bundle $E$ and curvature $F_{\nabla}$  on it.Then we can define the top Chern class as $det(\frac{i}{2\pi}F_{\nabla})$.

Then we view $E$ as a even dimension real bundle and define a Euler class on it via the Pfaffian.

My question is, do these two class equal with each other(maybe differ by a constant)?(not just represent the same cohomology class)

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Have you worked it out explicitly for the case of a complex line bundle? That should answer your question.

Comment: @TedShifrin Excuse me, do you means the riemannian suface case? In this case I think the formula $i\Omega=K\omega$ tell me they coincide, where $\Omega$ is the curvature of complex line bundle and $K$ the Gaussian curvature, $\omega$ the associated form of metric. But I have no idea for the higher dimension.

Comment: Well, no, I meant a general complex line bundle on a general manifold. By the splitting principle, you can assume a general bundle splits as a sum of line bundles.

Comment: @TedShifrin I am not familiar with the spiltting principle, I google it but I find that to understand it I should learn some topological definition of characteristic class which I don' learn yet，is there any reference in the language of connection and curvature？Actually I will learn the topological definition of characteristic class in the future but I want to convince myself this proposition is true now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\require{amsfonts}
\require{amsmath}$
Let $A\in \mathfrak{u}(n)$ and let $A_{\mathbb{R}} \in \mathfrak{so}(2n)$ be the associated real matrix. Then one has
$$ \det(iA) = Pf(A_\mathbb{R}).$$
If $n=1$, $A= i\lambda$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ then $A_\mathbb{R} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \lambda \\ -\lambda & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$
You can calculate $$Pf(A_\mathbb{R}) = -\lambda  = \det(iA). $$ In general this follows by diagonalizing $A$, then $A_\mathbb{R}$ has $2\times 2$ blocks on its diagonal and for any $2n\times 2n$ matrix the Pfaffian transforms like this:
$$ Pf(B A_\mathbb{R} B^\top) = \det(B)Pf(A).$$

**Edit**: I wanted to add that there are two different sign conventions here. Since the Pfaffian is usually normalised requiring that $$ Pf\left(\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\right) = \pm 1$$ (either plus or minus $1$) one might has to adjust the definitions. In Milnor & Stasheff's book they use the $+1$ convention and define the total chern class by
$$ c(A) = \det(I + A/(2\pi i)).$$ While for example wikipedia uses $+1$ and $c(A) = \det(I + iA/(2\pi))$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern_class#Via_the_Chern%E2%80%93Weil_theory)), so they *should* define $e(A_\mathbb{R}) = Pf(-A/(2\pi))$.